# Installing Python Packages (pip) via TCP

Tags: python, pip

Is it possible to define whether pip uses TCP or UDP to make connections? Currently I observe that traffic is blocked by my firewall because only TCP is allowed but pip tries to use UDP.

I am using pip inside of conda from the Windows Command Prompt.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `pip` uses HTTPS (TCP) by default. What kind of UDP traffic did you observe? DNS? And BTW in UDP you don't make connections as in TCP and both are not simply interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Traffic goes to the standard port on the proxy (not 53 for DNS).

Answer (score 1):

Pip always uses `TCP`, as `http` / `https` via `UDP` does not exist.

Try to post the exact error message and the exact command that you type, that causes this error.

The cause must be something else, than you assume (perhaps a `DNS` setup issue, perhaps the need for an http proxy, ...)